# Is this a normal shadow gap? Connection between a wall and the ceiling

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, building-design

I am currently checking out an appartment in which I noticed a strange connection between the side walls and the ceiling.

The guy told me it is a shadow gap which I then googled and it just didn't seem to fit what I found, at least the way it is constructed/oriented. It looks as they made the walls thicker but not all the way to the ceiling.

I attached a file how it looks, the picture is not to scale. It is a tiny gap where the ceiling and the side wall meet.

The building is a one story concrete building, and the apparmant is on the first floor( also the last floor) so the buliding roof is on top of it.

Is this a normal thing in building? Did any one of you encountered/made this before?

Thank you very much[image]

Edit: added a picture[image]

Edit2: Higher quality image[image]

Comment: Take a real photo so we can see what you are trying to describe.

Comment: @SolarMike I added aphoto. This is from a website. I can take one with higher quality but I think it can be seen here what I mean when compared with the sketch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sketch indicates a short roof overhang (exterior) or a ceiling decorating block/trim (interior). For the latter case, if it is located a short distance from the ceiling, then it can be called a "shadow gap", which is made to create a more interesting visual effect. At times, it also has the function to absorb sound by using sound-absorbing (foam) panels.

Comment: Shadow gap or spider gap?

Comment: @SolarMike **Spider Gap** is the pass in the ridge between Spider Meadow and Lyman Lakes. Start out on the Phelps Creek Trail to its end in Spider Meadow,  whereas a "shadow gap" is an architectural feature on the wall or ceiling. :)

Comment: @r13  I googled about shadow gaps but as far as my short research goes, they mostly point upwards and not sideways as in this case. I couldn't find an example like this.

Comment: @refa Shadow gap is anything to create a 3D visual effect, https://www.aixfoam.com/info/lexicon/sound-absorber-shadow-gap#:~:text=A%20shadow%20gap%20is%20generally%20a%20gap%20between,for%20example%2C%20with%20visible%20cladding%20or%20wood%20coverings. If you want to know exactly what you have seen in that apartment, you should upload a photo of it. As I have said, it could be something else.

Comment: @r13 I uploaded a photo, I think it can be seen what I mean with the sketch. Regarding shadow gaps, I saw that they mostly go "upwards" ie. extend "into the ceiling". In this case the gap extends horizontaly, into the sidewall. Anyway, I will make a higher quality photo today and upload it later. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you enlarge the photo and stare at it hard, you may see there seems a narrow white strip (trim) below the shadow. If that is the case, it is one type of "shadow gap" effect.

Comment: @r13 Here is a higher quality one. Except of the load-bearing walls this is on every other. And they are plaster-board.

Comment: It looks like a lousy job of roof border trim on the wall-ceiling joint. Though it is provided for a better visual effect, I would be reluctant to call it a shadow gap but a decorative border/edge trim.